# How to clear solace queues without consuming messages?

Tags: spring-boot, jms

I tried finding similar question but could not find the best possible solution for my problem. I am using spring boot in my application and integrated solace queues in my code. I am able to read the messages from solace queues by using following piece of code:

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {
    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new PoolingConnectionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

With the help of spring boot all the properties like VPN are picked up from properties file and ConnectionFactory gets created. 
Below is the code to read messages:

```
@Configuration
public class QueueConfig {
    @Value("${destination.name}")
    private String destination;
    @Value("${destination.isPubSub:false}")
    private boolean pubSubDomain;
    @Value("${maxConsumers:1}")
    private int maxConsumers;
    @Value("${destination.autoStartup:true}")
    private boolean autoStartup;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow queueFlow(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(jmsConnectionFactory).autoStartup(autoStartup)
                        .configureListenerContainer(
                                c -> c.transactionManager(transactionManager).pubSubDomain(pubSubDomain).maxConcurrentConsumers(maxConsumers))
                        .destination(destination))
                .transform(Transformers.fromJson(HashMap[].class)).log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, m -> MessageFormat
                        .format("Processing {0} {1} records...", ((Object[]) m.getPayload()).length, m.getHeaders().get("table")))
                .route(getTableRouter()).get();

    }

    private ExpressionEvaluatingRouter getTableRouter() {
        ExpressionEvaluatingRouter router = new ExpressionEvaluatingRouter("headers['table']");
        router.setResolutionRequired(false);
        router.setDefaultOutputChannel(new NullChannel());
        return router;
    }
```

According to the type of message, the service actuator is located and the message gets processed. It is working completely fine for us.

However, there are some situations in which we need to delete the spooled messages from the queue quickly without consuming them. Is there any way we can do so in the current set up which I have mentioned here.

I tried via queue browser but there is no such option available there

Answer (score 0):

JMS itself does not define a method to 'clear the queue without consuming messages'. This type of operation is left to the provider-specific admin API's. Your best bet is to consume them with JMS and just don't process them.

I think the [Solace SEMP Admin API](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/swagger-ui/index.html#/queue/deleteMsgVpnQueue) defines deletions of objects but no fast clearing. Maybe [re-creating](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/swagger-ui/index.html#/queue/createMsgVpnQueue) the queue would work, but it won't be pretty.